representative value of a distribution for Monte Carlo simulation
I have a monte carlo simulation that samples three independent variables from their respective (continuous and skewed) distribution. I need to fix one variable and only sample from the other two distributions. What fixed value would be the best representative? median?

Noone knows. This is domain knowledge which you have and we didn't. You could try obvious three - median, mean, mode - and see
